# Can't see contents of array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm trying to scan through the contents of my array for a 3x3 tictactoe game. The below procedure is called when the user has had their go and it's now time for the computer to move.

The gameBoard array should be full of '?' at this point, except for the 'X' that the human player just placed. I just wanted to check how many '?' are in the array, these would be the available spaces for the computer to choose. I wanted to place the result in label2 just so I could check that it is working, but it's not. At this point it should show '8' in the label.

Thanks in advance

````
var
  i, iCount, j: Integer;
begin

  label1.Caption := 'Computer''s turn';
  // scan through gameboard to check available spaces
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    for j := 1 to 3 do

      if (gameBoard[i, j] = '?') then
      begin
        iCount := iCount + 1;

      end;
  Label2.Caption := inttostr(iCount);

end;```
````

Comment: What does the label show? You say it doesn't show 8 but you haven't told us what it does show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables in Delphi are not initialized, so iCount could have any value when the procedure runs. Set iCount to zero before starting the loops.

Comment: Thanks Keith, I tried but it just says 0 now.

Comment: @efiemu That would suggest that the array has no '?'s in it. What happens when you step through with the debugger?